# How to Launch a new page from href

Tags: button, href

I currently use button and trying to launch a new window passing parameter from mypage to the new page like this

```
  <input type="button" name="launchpg" id="launchpg" value="LaunchPage" onclick="launch_page('<%=list_process_url%>',this.form.myform.options[this.form.myform.options.selectedIndex].value);"/>
```

Javascript is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

//call servlet 
function launch_new_window(list_process_url,smart_id)
{        
    popupWindow = window.open(list_process_url+"&id="+id,'List Process Page',
        'scrollbars = yes');
}
```

I am trying to replace button with href link as in..

document.location='main.jsp?PAGE=myPage.jsp&id='+this.form.myform.options[this.form.myfom.options.selectedIndex].value;

I would like to use the same javascript for launching a new window passing the parameter to the script function.

The code however doesn't seem to work as it says Form is not valid for href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question:

```
  <a href="#" onclick="window.open('main.jsp?PAGE=NewPage.jsp&id=<%=l.getID().intValue()%>','_‌​new');">Open New Window </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to wherever you want to launch a new page from:

```
window.location.href = "pageName.html";

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
            <script>
                $(function () {
                        <!--Some Logic-->
                        <!--window.location.href = "NewWindowName.html";-->          
                    }

                    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                        openNewWindow();
                    });

                    function openNewWindow()
                    {                        
                        window.location.href = "NewWindowName.html";
                    }
                });
            </script>        
        <article>           
            <button id="btnSave">Save Data</button>
        </article>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I added this but didn't work -                                          I added the below line, it doesn't seem to work                                                                             <a href=" window.location.href ="main.jsp?PAGE=myPage.jsp&id="<%=l.getID().intValue()%>">OpenNewWindow </a>

Comment: I Used jquery to accomplish this